# Configuring Temporary Folder used by a Web Service Client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, executable

We have a stand alone .NET console program EXE that upload a file to sharepoint using sharepoint web service. This is run by corporate scheduler. Due to restrictions in folder permissions imposed by server security team, we are getting below error during this upload.

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Local\Temp\7rcptgnc.tmp'

The application code do not explicitly access the temporary folder , it only calls the web service with file stream.

**Question is :** Is there a way to provide a setting in exe.config to use a specific folder for temp files to prevent it from using default temp folder.

Changing environment variables to change the windows temp folders and adding permissions to the above temp folder are not preferred options.

Comment: Is the username of the logged-in user "TEMP"?

Comment: This is a server , so no logged in user exists.  The program is run by the user account of the scheduler and that account is not TEMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to the above question.  The XML serialization for web service call was creating temp files in the default temp folder to which the permissions are restricted by server admins.

Following setting in app/web config file lets me configure a custom directory for this.

```
<system.xml.serialization> 
  <xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation="c:\\foo"/> 
</system.xml.serialization>
```

I have not looked in to if the temp files are only created during a file upload using web service or any web service call creates a temp file.